# Insert into change value if duplicate entry

Tags: mysql

I have this sql query:

```
INSERT INTO my_table
SELECT id, name, type
FROM other_table
```

I have this row: 1,bob,male

And I try insert: 1,bob,male

So, I have a duplicate entry error and I want change my insert value with an increment by one so after I would have two rows:

1. bob,male <=NOT UPDATED
2. bob,male

I don't want update the existing row, if I have a duplicate entry error. The insert increments the id value. So, I think `ON DUPLICATE KEY` isn't the solution.

UPDATE:

If I use a trigger like this:

```
DELIMITER | 
CREATE TRIGGER incremente_primary BEFORE INSERT ON my_table FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
IF( EXISTS( SELECT * FROM my_table )) THEN  
SET NEW.id = NEW.id + 1; 
END IF; 
END | 
DELIMITER ;
```

It doesn't work because a trigger can read only one line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find a solution, i use a cursor:

```
DROP PROCEDURE proc_incremente;
DELIMITER |
CREATE PROCEDURE proc_incremente()
BEGIN

    DECLARE var_name, var_type VARCHAR(100);

    DECLARE var_id INT;

    DECLARE end TINYINT(1) DEFAULT 0;

    DECLARE cursor_incremente CURSOR
        FOR SELECT * FROM other_table;

    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET end = 1;

    OPEN cursor_incremente;

    loop_cursor: LOOP

        FETCH cursor_incremente INTO var_id, var_name, var_type;

        IF end = 1 THEN
            LEAVE loop_cursor;
        END IF;

        WHILE ( EXISTS( SELECT * my_table WHERE id = var_id) IS TRUE) DO
            SET var_id = var_id + 1;
        END WHILE;

        INSERT INTO my_table(id,name,type) VALUES(var_id,var_name,var_type);

    END LOOP;

    CLOSE cursor_incremente;

END |
DELIMITER ;

CALL proc_incremente();
```

Answer (score 1):

As per your requirement, you need to set auto_increment property for your id and then just insert other columns except id, so that it can be auto_increment like below-

```
INSERT INTO my_table (name,type)
SELECT name, type
FROM other_table;
```

If you just want to ignore if there is duplicate then you can use-

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO my_table
SELECT id,name, type
FROM other_table;
```

Comment: I use this example just for simplify my problem. But in real, my primiary key is 4 columns and the problem is just the value of one column. If just i add +1 in this column, i will not duplicate the key.

Comment: I think to solve my problem, I need to use a trigger.

Answer (score 0):

make sure that the primary key isn't the name or the type. Because you can input duplicate rows as long as you do not duplicate primary keys